# Refresh database in banshee

Tags: banshee, cron, libraries

I have a library of around 20k songs and it takes forever to banshee to index it. I would like to force a database refresh by cron. My PC starts every night to do the backup with my cloud backup service and I would like to take the chance to refresh the banshee database at the same time.

What can be the command to run?

Answer (score 1):

If you are knowledgeable with any scripting that can do DBus, you can do the following:

At the session bus, invoke `CreateIndexer` on interface `org.bansheeproject.CollectionIndexer`, invoke `Index` on the returned object path and await the `IndexingComplete` signal, then exit the wait and issue `ShutDown`. If you keep the mpris2 plugin active, you then can shutdown banshee gracefully by issuing `Quit` on the `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2` interface.

As a side note, your cloud backup solution may also be eligible for DBus remote control so you can await its completion somehow and send the computer into sleep after the fact via the `Suspend` invocation on `org.freedesktop.UPower` at the system bus.

Comment: I am not knowledable in DBus, but your answer makes me want to be, I am heading to Google right away for a DBus research. Thanks